# Overlap of colored rows

Tags: tabu

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}%

\tabulinesep=_1em^1em
\everyrow{\tabucline[1pt]{-}}

\begin{tabu}{@{}XX[3,L]} 
   \tabucline[1.5pt]{-} 
      blabla & 
      blabla
   \tabularnewline
   \taburowcolors 1{green!30 .. green!30}
      \multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{\textit Pause} 
   \tabularnewline
   \taburowcolors 1{white .. white}
      blabla &
      blabla
   \tabularnewline 
   \taburowcolors 1{green!30 .. green!30}
      \multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{\textit Pause} 
   \tabularnewline
   \taburowcolors 1{white .. white}
      blabla &
      blabla
   \tabularnewline \tabucline[1.5pt]-
\end{tabu} 

\end{document}
```

wich results in

[image]

Unfortunately there is an overlap in the colored rows. How is it possible to align the colored rows with the beginning of the horizontal lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drop that `@{}c` specification, use `c` instead, as far as I know, `\multicolumn` does allow for such use, but in this case, it does not work.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}%

\tabulinesep=_1em^1em
\everyrow{\tabucline[1pt]{-}}

\begin{tabu}{@{}XX[3,L]} 
   \tabucline[1.5pt]{-} 
      blabla & 
      blabla
   \tabularnewline
   \taburowcolors 1{green!30 .. green!30}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Pause}} 
   \tabularnewline
   \taburowcolors 1{white .. white}
      blabla &
      blabla
   \tabularnewline 
   \taburowcolors 1{green!30 .. green!30}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Pause}} 
   \tabularnewline
   \taburowcolors 1{white .. white}
      blabla &
      blabla
   \tabularnewline \tabucline[1.5pt]-
\end{tabu} 

\end{document}
```

[image]